# C# CSOM Sharepoint Access with Tokens

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, token, csom

I have been really struggling with getting Access Tokens working with our Sharepoint site and still no luck.

The problem is when I access our site using the SharepointOnlineCredentials it works fine, well I can query the sharepoint  as follows and this works but I want to use the new token stuff that just doesn't work for me

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharepointSiteUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = GetCredentials();
    var web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    if (context.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found title");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", web.Title);
}

private static SharePointOnlineCredentials GetCredentials()
{
    SecureString password = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "MyPassword".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
    return new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myname@mycompany.com", password);
}
```

So now for the code that doesn't work

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());

ClientCredential clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCredentials);
Console.WriteLine("Token Type: {0} \nExpires: {1} \nToken: {2}", authenticationResult.AccessTokenType, authenticationResult.ExpiresOn, authenticationResult.AccessToken);

using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointSiteUrl, authenticationResult.AccessToken))
{
    var web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    if (context.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("Title"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found title");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", web.Title);
}
```

Now when I run this the web.Title throws an error and the context.Web display '**Cannot find the method on the object instance.**'

The web.Title in the debugger also states '**The property or field 'Title' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested**.'

I really would love some help with this as it's turned impossible for me. Thanks :)

Do I need to be aware or granting access somewhere else? as its strange that the first one works!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are explicitly requesting the `Title` property from the CSOM end-point:

```
context.Credentials = GetCredentials();
var web = context.Web;
context.Load(web, w => w.Title); // explicitly requesting the Title property
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Whereas in the second example there is no     `context.Load(web, w => w.Title);`

Maybe this is the issue?